# How to get javascript to prompt a question a set number times

Tags: javascript, random

Im trying to write a simple program that asks the user to guess a random number a set number of times.
So far I have the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Decisions and Loops</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
<script>

var rNum = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 30);

var myInput = Number (prompt ("Please enter your Guess: "));


if (myInput == rNum) {
    alert("Good guess");
    } 
    else if (myInput >= rNum){
        alert((prompt ("Sorry, guess if too low, try again"));
    } 
    else {
    alert((prompt ("Sorry, guess if too high, try again"));
    }

</script>
</html>
```

Two issues
1. For some reason this is not working.
2. How do I get the program to iterate through the loops a number of times?
Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Use a loop like `for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++)`

Comment: BTW, your parentheses aren't balanced in the `alert()` lines.

Comment: `>=` should be `<`.

Comment: `guess if` should be `guess is`

Comment: Thanks to all who posted. Appreciate the suggestions, still at the intro stage!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic implementation with few logic fixes could be like this:

```
// To limit the number of prompts, or else loop might go on forever
var max_try = 5;

function ShowQuiz() {
   var rNum = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 30);
   var myInput = Number(prompt("Please enter your Guess: "));

   if (myInput == rNum) {
      alert("Good guess");
   } else if (myInput < rNum) {
      alert("Sorry, your guess is too low, try again");
      if (--max_try > 0) ShowQuiz()
   } else {
      alert("Sorry, your guess is too high, try again");
      if (--max_try > 0) ShowQuiz()
   }
}

ShowQuiz();
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you

Comment: how would I ask this program to make a statement at the end of the break, i.e. it gives the used i numTimesToAsk then given the randomly selected number rNum?

Answer (score 1):

```
var rNum = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 30);

var myInput;
var numTimesToAsk = 3;

for (var i = 0; i < numTimesToAsk; i++) {
    myInput = Number (prompt ("Please enter your Guess: "));
    if(myInput === rNum) {
      alert("Good guess");
      break; //if you want the loop to stop here since they guessed correctly
    } else if (myInput >= rNum) {
      alert("Sorry, guess is too low, try again");
    } else {
      alert("Sorry, guess is too high, try again");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that!

Comment: how would I ask this program to make a statement at the end of the break, i.e. it gives the used i numTimesToAsk then given the randomly selected number rNum?

Comment: @Peadar08 you want to tell the user how many tries they took? You could change `alert("Good guess");` to `alert("Good guess. You guessed the random number, " + rNum + ", in " + i + 1 + " tries");` The reason you'd need `i+1` is because it will always have the value of the total number of tries.